# Model fails to converge in glmer() after trying different optimizers

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, convergence

I am struggling with this specific mixed model which keeps failing to converge after trying different optimizers. In the model, the response variable is binary (0,1) with 4 numeric predictors and 3 random effects.

The most recurrent message is: "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with x negative eigenvalues"

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Note that vectors from randomx vectors were transformed to characters so that R do not confuse them with objects, since I did not put quotation marks between each of these.

```
response <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
fixed1 <- c(104,149,120,93,90,54,68,29,74,86,71,83,39,95,89,122,41,188,142,63,129,59,90,132,164,91,87,76,62,68,76,102,96,91,92,91,101,108,85,79,95,66,63,87,54,87,92,93,126,118,76,102,43,96,94,159,79,88,68,66,105,139,83,10,84,149,94,133,117,105,92,106,85,77,56,17,132,94,138,35,111,81,91,102,53,130,77,115,93,58,42,101,91,86,126,59,166,116,136,157,74,92,99,145,89,77,106,84)
fixed2 <- c(24.07,24.07,24.07,24.07,23.63,22.47,22.47,23.9,23.9,23.14,23.69,23.35,23.35,23.35,23.35,23.35,22.85,22.17,22.17,23.18,23.18,23.18,22.17,23.3,23.3,23.3,23.91,23.91,23.46,23.22,23.22,23.22,23.22,24.64,23.91,23.54,23.54,23.54,24.06,24.06,24.06,22.92,23.35,22.49,23.72,23.72,23.65,23.65,23.65,23.54,24.09,24.09,24.09,21.88,23.04,24.03,23.38,23.38,23.38,23.81,23.81,22.3,22.3,22.3,23.9,23.24,23.24,22.47,22.47,23.16,23.88,23.88,23.94,23.94,23.94,23.65,24.23,24.23,22.96,23.29,23.29,23.29,24.47,24.47,24.47,24.47,23.6,24.17,23.12,23.04,24.37,22.68,24.56,24.56,23.88,23.88,23,23,21.61,21.61,23.91,23.76,23.4,23.4,25.58,23.05,22.81,24.08)
fixed3 <- c(12,12,12,12,6,2,2,12,12,13,4,11,11,11,11,11,13,15,15,17,7,15,15,8,8,8,6,6,2,11,11,11,11,15,18,17,17,17,13,13,13,10,12,18,10,10,3,3,3,4,18,18,18,7,10,12,18,18,18,6,6,4,4,6,7,17,9,16,4,9,2,4,11,4,4,6,16,13,17,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,5,15,16,12,12,11,6,6,13,13,2,2,15,8,15,2,13,13,5,2,11,12)
fixed4 <- c(3,3,6,5,2,2,5,2,4,4,5,2,2,3,3,6,6,2,4,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,4,7,3,4,5,4,3,2,2,2,4,2,5,4,2,2,3,2,2,2,4,6,4,9,2,2,2,4,3,5,3,4,5,2,3,2,2,2,2,4,3,4,2,3,2,4,5,4,6,6,2,4,4,2,3,6,2,3,5,4,4,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,4,5,2,4,2,2,2,7,4,3,2,7,4)
random1 <- as.character(quote(c(A,B,C,D,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,B,C,D,E,B,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,A,B,A,C,C,A,B,C,D,A,A,A,B,C,A,B,C,B,B,A,B,C,A,B,D,B,B,C,E,C,C,A,B,C,D,B,C,A,C,D,B,B,C,C,E,C,C,B,B,C,D,B,C,D,B,B,C,D,B,C,D,E,B,E,D,B,C,C,C,D,D,E,C,D,C,D,D,D,C,D,C,C,D,E)))[-1]
random2 <- as.character(quote(c(st110,st110,st110,st110,st207,st205,st205,st113,st113,st112,st115,st125,st125,st125,st125,st125,st111,st107,st107,st101a,st114,st101,st102,st104,st104,st104,st206,st206,st209,st119,st119,st119,st119,st124,st120,st118,st118,st118,st123,st123,st123,st116,st112a,st108,st106,st106,st208,st208,st208,st115,st108,st108,st108,st114,st103,st204,st120,st120,st120,st105,st105a,st210,st210,st207,st122,st118,st203,st119a,st115,st203,st209b,st210,st119,st119b,st119b,st219,st121,st123,st118,st101b,st101b,st101b,st109b,st109b,st109b,st109b,st127,st117,st121,st203b,st204,st125,st105b,st105b,st112,st112,st205,st214,st102,st104,st107,st221,st111,st111,st127,st225,st109a,st203b)))[-1]
random3 <- as.character(quote(c(M34101,M34101,M34101,M34101,M34117,M34120,M34120,M34128,M34128,M34133,M34135,M34136,M34136,M34136,M34136,M34136,M34140,M34141,M34141,M34155,M34155,M34155,M34157,M34162,M34162,M34162,M34172,M34172,M34176,M34178,M34178,M34178,M34178,M34182,M34183,M34185,M34185,M34185,M34186,M34186,M34186,M34189,M36501,M36504,M36510,M36510,M36514,M36514,M36514,M36519,M36521,M36521,M36521,M36524,M36541,M36569,M36572,M36572,M36572,M36584,M36584,M36590,M36590,M36590,M36592,M36616,M36616,M36618,M36618,M36628,M36636,M36636,M36646,M36646,M36646,M36653,M36659,M36659,M36664,M36667,M36667,M36667,M36668,M36668,M36668,M36668,M36669,M36684,M36685,M36741,M36757,M36771,M36797,M36797,M36822,M36822,M36833,M36833,M36845,M36845,M36856,M36892,M49816,M49816,M65102,M65105,M65128,M65135)))[-1]

library(lme4)
library(optimx)
glmm1 <- glmer(response ~ scale(fixed1) + scale(fixed2) + scale(fixed3) + scale(fixed4)
               + (1|random1) + (1|random2) + (1|random3), family="binomial")
glmm2 <- glmer(response ~ scale(fixed1) + scale(fixed2) + scale(fixed3) + scale(fixed4)
               + (1|random1) + (1|random2) + (1|random3),
               family="binomial", control = glmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))
glmm3 <- glmer(response ~ scale(fixed1) + scale(fixed2) + scale(fixed3) + scale(fixed4)
               + (1|random1) + (1|random2) + (1|random3),
               family="binomial", control = glmerControl(
                 optimizer ='optimx', optCtrl=list(method='L-BFGS-B')))
```

Comment: Have you checked for high correlation between variables? You may need to drop some variables. Have you tried optimizer "optim"?

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks for the suggestion. There are no strong correlations between my predictors and variance inflation factors (vifs) indicate no multicollinearity problem. In addition, I didn't see any strong association between a variable included as a random effect and any of my predictors.

Comment: @SergioNolazco Perhaps you don’t need all the random effects. Typically binary data do not contain a lot of information and many times even if you have a complicated study design (e.g., multilevel) this may not be supported by the data.

Comment: @Dimitris Actually, my three random variables seems to be mandatory as all of these can have a non-trivial effect to be taken into account. These include the year the data was taken and the site (both expected to be very influential), and the ID of the individual.

Comment: @SergioNolazco if you have a repeated measurements study in which subjects are followed-up over time, you typically put the time as a random slope not as an extra grouping factor. I.e., `glmer(... + (year | id) + (1 | session), data = <your_data>)` or `glmer(... +(year | id / session, data = <your_data>)`.

Comment: @user2974951 I've take a better look at my variables and it looks like random2 variable is highly associated with fixed3 variable. This redundancy seems to be problematic and by removing random2, the model converges with some optimizers.

Comment: @SergioNolazco I have a similar problem. I am running a glmer family binomial. The response variable is the proportion between infested (Numero_foglie_minate) and healthy (Foglie_sane) leaves and it is measured 7 times ("Data_rilievo) on the same individuals ("ID_pianta"). I have tried this

`model_interazione <- glmer(cbind(Numero_foglie_minate, Foglie_sane) ~ Trattamento*Data_rilievo + Blocco + (1 | ID_pianta),
                           data = data_infestate,family=binomial)`

Not sure whether time should be fixed or random effect. In case it is fixed, I get many convergence issues.